# Append element to a div only inside the parentcontainer

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I append .div4 to .div1 onLy on its parent container without it also appends to the next container with the same div? I tried the basic jQuery appendTo but this sets .div4 on all the .div1 elements in my DOM.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
    <div class="div4"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Update: changed invalid HTML. Using this script now (replace dummy divs with my actual divs):

```
var $this = $('span.conditionHilite.refurbHilite');
$this.appendTo($this.closest('.itembox.centerbox.col.span_1_of_3').find('.image.col1'));
```

Problem now is that if my page consist of more then one container with"span.conditionHilite.refurbHilite" it will append the total amount of these elements inside each parentcontainer instead of just the one.

Comment: You have duplicate `id` attributes, which means your HTML is invalid.

Comment: It seems you're using id's and classes the wrong way around; id's are intended to be unique whereas classes are intended to be reusable.

Comment: Unfortunaly this is how the HTML is setup and nothing I can change. Its my companys shop platform - each container is a product with the same html. Some of the product have a status though inside a new element - this I want to move by appending it. but doing so adds the staus to each container - I want to keep it inside its parent conainer.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried to append an element to more than one target element with jQuery, it will clone that element however many times is required. If you only want to append `.div4` to the `.div1` element within its same container element, you'll need to explicitly select that element. Something like this:

```
var $this = $('.div4');
$this.appendTo($this.closest('.container').find('.div1'));
```

That uses `.closest()` to traverse up the DOM tree to find the containing element, then `.find()` to look within that containing element for the `.div1` element. With your current DOM structure that will only ever be a single element, so the `.div4` element is simply moved, without any clones being created.

**Note**: As Rory McCrossan pointed out, you're re-using IDs in your HTML and it is therefore invalid. I've used a class selector in the code above on the assumption that you'll fix your invalid HTML by switching from `id="container"` to `class="container"`. If - as stated in the comments - you absolutely can't change that, then the `'[id="container"]'` selector should work instead.

Comment: My mistake. My HTML do have class for its container. This kinda works - it keeps the element inside its parentcontainer. But. My code is repeating- I have several containers with my target div - on my testpage I tried your script I had 4 containers with the .div1, so it appended 4 .div1 on each container containg the said element.

Comment: @Xeptor The `var $this = $('.div4')` line in my code is a placeholder for a line that gets a reference to the single specific element you actually want to work with. When does this code run?

Comment: @Antohony Griest Well the specific element will show up inside other containers aswell - My hope was it would append the element on each of them - which is does, but it also repeats it with all the target elements it find on document load, which gives me the amount of the specific element inside each of the parent containers. It loads on document ready.

Comment: @Xeptor Update the question with your code, please.